# Ambigous member request from variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

This makes no sense to me. GCC is complaining that the call below in `main()` to `processMsg()` is ambiguous, even though all of the template-created `processMsg()` calls are reported back as candidates. I've tried implementing this variadic template prototype three different ways and they all lead back to this same issue of ambiguous request. I did get closer when I broke the template implementation up into different cases for  and  but then I could the compiler could only resolve the first lookup in the tuple.

I've pasted a small example. I'm sure I'm missing something simple....

```
#include <tuple>

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
//
class MessageBase
{
  public:
    MessageBase( const int _id ) : m_id( _id ) {}
    virtual int getMessageID() const { return( m_id ); }

  private:
    const int m_id;
};

#define MESSAGE( NAME, VAL ) \
  class Message##NAME : public MessageBase { \
    public: \
      Message##NAME() : MessageBase( VAL ) { } \
  };

  MESSAGE( One, 1 );
  MESSAGE( Two, 2 );
  MESSAGE( Ten, 10 );

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
//

template< typename T > 
struct MyMessageInterface {
    virtual void processMsg( const T& t ) { } 
};

template< typename... T > 
struct MyMessageHandler : public MyMessageInterface< T >...
{};

template< typename... T > 
struct MyMessageHandler< std::tuple< T... > > 
  : public MyMessageInterface< T >...
{};


//----------------------------------------------------------------------
//
typedef std::tuple< MessageOne, MessageTwo, MessageTen > Foople;

int main()
{
  MyMessageHandler< Foople > mmh;
  mmh.processMsg( MessageOne() );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a forwarder to the specialization of `MyMessageHandler`:

```
template< typename... T > 
struct MyMessageHandler< std::tuple< T... > > 
  : public MyMessageInterface< T >...
{
    template< typename U >
    void processMsg( const U& u )
    {
        MyMessageInterface< U >::processMsg( u );
    }
};
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93ddbab7b2dfc22d)

The reason you need to do something like this (or what Jarod42 proposed) is that the virtual methods of the base classes are not visible from the derived class when the name is ambiguous. Normally you'd add a using declaration to pull in what you need, but in your case a forwarder might be easier.

Comment: Hmm... so the plan for this was (next) to derive a concrete MessageHandler object from the above and overload the processMsg() calls in the derived class. I'm guessing that won't work? (I tried it and it doesn't seem to.)

Comment: @RMHarris157 One option which we use in our company's codebase is to call the virtual function `v_processMsg` which allows it to be overwritten later on and have the non-virtual `processMsg` forward to it. That way the interface/forwarder `processMsg` can be put into the right place and does not interfere with the virtual part and the class hierarchy.

Comment: So, the in context of the above, I changed the MyMessageInterface to: `virtual void vProcessMsg( const MessageT& ) = 0;` and changed the call in the forwarder to `MyMessageInterface< MessageT >::vProcessMsg( _msg );` When I try to compile the .C that includes the derived definition of the above, the linker complains that it can't find the base class implementations of vProcessMsg for each class in the tuple. Am I missing another layer of indirection somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

You may rewrite `MyMessageHandler` as follow: [Live example](https://ideone.com/TFdV90)

```
template <typename... Ts> struct MyMessageHandler;

template <typename T> struct MyMessageHandler<T>
{
    virtual void processMsg(const T&) { }
};

template <typename T, typename...Ts>
struct MyMessageHandler<T, Ts...> : MyMessageHandler<T>, MyMessageHandler<Ts...>
{
    using MyMessageHandler<T>::processMsg;
    using MyMessageHandler<Ts...>::processMsg;
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct MyMessageHandler<std::tuple<Ts...>> : public MyMessageHandler<Ts...>
{
};
```

Comment: An explanation why this solves it would help to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to (unfortunately) explicitly disambiguate the base class that you want to call:

```
int main()
{
    MyMessageHandler< Foople > mmh;
    mmh.MyMessageInterface<MessageOne>::processMsg( MessageOne() );
    return 0;
}
```

You can bury the cast in another template if you like:

```
template <typename Handler, typename Message>
void caller(Handler &h, const Message &m)
{
    h.MyMessageInterface<Message>::processMsg( m );
}

int main()
{
    MyMessageHandler< Foople > mmh;
    caller(mmh, MessageOne());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better to put the template method directly in the class : `template <typename... T>
struct MyMessageHandler : public MyMessageInterface<T>...
{
    template <typename T2>
    void processMsg(const T2& t)
    {
        MyMessageInterface<T2>::processMsg(t);
    }
};
` (https://ideone.com/oaqkk2)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that member look-up is ambiguous because all of the `MyMessageInterface<T>`s are a direct base class of `MyMessageHandler`.

We need to pull in the set of names into MyMessageHandler itself so that we can form the overload set with those names.

First approach might be to do something like: `using TMessageInterface<T>::processMsg;...` but of course that's not legal.

My suggestion would be to either do what @Jarod42 did to recursively pull in the `processMsg` functions, or you can do:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct MyMessageHandler : MyMessageInterface<Ts>... {

  template <typename Msg>
  void processMsg(const Msg &msg) {
    MyMessageInterface<Msg>::processMsg(msg);
  }

};
```

which invokes the specific base class' `processMsg`.